# Bootstrap next and previous button in modal window

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-window

I am using bootstrap modal window with next and previous buttons for my project, by default "modal-footer" is in the bottom. I want to keep next and previous button on left and right with vertically center of the modal window.

Please suggest.

Comment: Share the code what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you can try bootstrap carousel combine with modal

```css
body {
    padding-top: 20px;
    
}

.btn-default {
    top: 25%;
    left:25%; 
    color: #999; 
    background: #fffccc; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container text-center">

<h1> Click Me </h1>
<!-- Large modal -->
<button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Large modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
     <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1200x600/555/000&text=One" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        One Image
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1200x600/fffccc/000&text=Two" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Another Image
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="item">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1200x600/fcf00c/000&text=Three" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Another Image
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button> 
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```